# Django AWS S3 - 400 "Bad Request" - Can't access image from bucket

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently decided to merge the images used in my application from a static folder in my root directory to an AWS S3 bucket.

Unfortunately, I am getting this error when I open my app in a browser:
`localhost/:65 GET https://django-plantin-bugtracker-files.s3.amazonaws.com/profile_pics/aragorn_SztKYs6.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA3KFS7YZNOMSRYG3O&Signature=fYWSQFdzTvtOF9OXAfw9yqfGyQc%3D&E`

It is strange because I can access the image URL directly (for example https://django-plantin-bugtracker-files.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default.jpg), which leads me to believe that my app is just not accessing it properly.

I unblocked all public access on my S3 bucket and added these lines of codes to the following files:

In my app's `settings.py` I added:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=config('AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

In my S3 bucket's `Bucket Policy`:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::django-plantin-bugtracker-files/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my S3 bucket's `CORS`:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Does anyone know why my images won't appear? The webpage loads fine and there is no error from Django.

The images look like this:

[image: Example of image not loaded]

Comment: 'unblocked all public access on my S3 bucket " - what about account level public access settings?

Comment: This is what I have so far:

Block all public access
 Off

Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)
 Off

Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
 Off

Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies
 Off

Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies
 Off

Comment: Does the bucket use KMS encryption?

Comment: I disabled the `Default Encryption` when creating the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was wrong. I was missing this line of code in the `settings.py` file of my application folder. Adding it solved the problem and the images are now appearing.

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked and your file i**s publicity available as expected**:

```
curl https://django-plantin-bugtracker-files.s3.amazonaws.com/profile_pics/aragorn_SztKYs6.jpg
```

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 17532
```

So this is not a problem with bucket policy or S3. It must be something specific to your application.